# Select records based on count of other records

Tags: sql

I have a data table like

```
ID category
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  2
5  4
```

I wish to select all records that fall into two given categories i and j (for instance i=1 and j=4 would return records 1, 2 and 5). But here's the twist: if one of the of the categories has no records, the query should return an empty set. For instance if I query for i=1 and j=3.
Can this be done, solely using SQL?

I've been trying to make an intermediate count table, but I'm afraid my sql isn't up to par.

Comment: you can try for SQL `CASE` expression. And accordingly you can put your query in the CASE expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write down what you said, will give:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE category=1)>0 
  AND (SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE category=4)>0
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/ybkitFgE)

or, slightly different:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (SELECT count(distinct category) FROM table1 WHERE category IN (1,4))=2
```

P.S.  I choose to use `mysql` in the DbFiddle, but this should work in  other DBMS's too.

EDIT: Also filtering on that `category` should be done:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE category IN (1,4)
  and (SELECT count(distinct category) FROM table1 WHERE category IN (1,4))=2
```

Comment: The where clause in your answer and DBFIDDLE  should also contain "AND (category=1 or category=4)", otherwise the records with category=2 also gets selected. Other than that, this is exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @BeeJee: You are correct!, so I added the filtering on category

Answer (score 0):

1. have you tried `SELECT` all `WHERE` the record is not `NULL`?
   Try it and respond if it did not work.
2. Try only `SELECT` the 1s and 4s for example in your table.